# How to export SSRS report to A3 Standard (4:3) Orientation otherwise pptx default orientation

Tags: reporting-services, export, report, powerpoint

I created the report area, body, header, and footer based on A3 dimensions,
it's exported very well on PDF, and printed well on A3 papers

But when export it to pptx, it shown in improper way, because the default size and orientation of pptx file

I tried to change the orientation and size on pptx after export, but because SSRS export the report as a pics, it didn't work.

I need to know how to control the default factors of pptx orientation and size during the exporting process.

Comment: You'll want to change the size/orientation of the PPTX file *before* you add any content.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg How to change this before exporting, since you have only the option to export to pptx from the ssrs, is there any other options.

Comment: I don't use ssrs, so I don't have any idea what it can / can't do, I'm afraid.